# Android httpURLconnection to spring secured angularJs webapp still unauthorized

Tags: android, angularjs, spring-security, httpurlconnection

Hi I have following code in my back end for web security configuration using spring boot security starter:

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
       .csrf().disable()                
       //.and()
       .httpBasic()
       .and()
       .authorizeRequests()                
       .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/*").permitAll()
       .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/geolocation").permitAll()
       .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/GeoLocationHandler").permitAll()
       .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/user/{userId}").authenticated()
       .anyRequest().authenticated();                
}
```

}

and in my android I have this

```
                    URL url = new URL(MainActivity.API_URL + "/user");
                Log.i(TAG, url.toString());
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

               httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
              httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "basic " 
+ Base64.encode("user:passcode".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));



                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
"application/json");
                httpURLConnection.connect();
```

However I still get unautherized 401 in android console log...And so I cant post to the webapp...Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs an answer I had to autherise the httpURLConnection from androids side and it worked. 
There are few answers on stackoverflow and one of them worked for me which uses the base64.encoder